# using Scapy to divide SCTP chunks

Tags: python, scapy

i am trying to use Scapy to divide a SCTP packet,but i can only divive a packet into different layers.
how can i divide SCTP into different chunks?
for example,using show() in Scapy, i know there are 2 chunks in  SCTP,but i dnt know how to get these two chunks.
[two chunks in SCTP packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiSqb.png)

Is there any ways to divide chunks in the same layer? or can i store the information from show() into an array?
Thanks^^

[SCTP packet structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZOu.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to traverse the chunks the same way you traverse the layers.

With a method like:

```
def expand(pkt):                                                                
    payload = []                                                                
    for p in pkt.payload:                                                       
        payload+=expand(p)                                                      
    return [pkt.name, payload]    

print(expand(pkt))                                                      
print(pkt.payload.payload.payload.name)
```

I get, for an SCTP package:

```
['Ethernet', ['IP', ['SCTP', ['SCTPChunkSACK', []]]]]
SCTPChunkSACK
```

**edit:**
For the content:

```
>>> print(pkt[SCTP][1])                                                     

b'\x03\x00\x00\x10\x7f\x8cD\x18\x00\x01\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

>>> print(pkt[SCTP][1].show())   

###[ SCTPChunkSACK ]###
  type      = sack
  flags     = 0x0
  len       = 16
  cumul_tsn_ack= 0x7f8c4418
  a_rwnd    = 106496
  n_gap_ack = 0
  n_dup_tsn = 0
  gap_ack_list= []
  dup_tsn_list= []
```

So you already have your (nested) list of chunks at pkt[SCTP][1:].

Comment: thanks for your answer..i am sorry that i didnt describe my question clearly...By using show() in Scapy or your expand() ,i have already known how many [sctpchunkdata] in this packet and their data....for the first picture in my question as an example,there are two...Now what i am trying to do is to divide and store these [sctpchunkdata], and make them looks like chunkdatalist = ['the first chunkdata', 'the second chunkdata', the third.....]      i have tried a lot,but all i got is all the chunkdatas,i dnt know how to divide them into different chunks

Comment: it doesn't work... As pkt[SCTP][1] includes SCTPChunkSACK,SCTPChunkData1 and SCTPChunkData2; pkt[SCTP][2] includes SCTPChunkData1 and SCTPChunkData2; pkt[SCTP][3] includes SCTPChunkData2...i have also tried pkt[SCTP][2][1] and pkt[SCTP][2][0], but the former just includes SCTPChunkData2 and the latter includes both data1 and 2...there is still no way to get only SCTPChunkData1 or only SCTPChunkSACK